# SQL Nested Subquery Referencing Grandparents Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a particularly complicated query for a report.  It selects several columns from a view, and it must build a column via aggregately concatenating several fields.  To complicate things further, the concatenation must contain 3 fields even if there are 0 in reality (The concatenation is comma delimited, so empty fields will still be noticed).

We are using Oracle 11.1.0.7.0.

To provide backward compatibility (not necessary) we used the xmlagg function to perform the concatenation, I believe that has been around since Oracle 8 or 9.

This example will be simplified but I feel provides sufficient information.  In other words, please do not focus on normalizing the table structure, this is strictly an example.

```
person_view
-----------
name
phone
address
position_id


position_table
--------------
position_id
position_title
```

So the query we currently have, and I admit to not being a SQL guru, is something like:

```
select
  name,
  phone,
  address,
  (select
     xmlagg(xmlelement(e, position_title || ',')).extract('//text()')
   from
     (select
        position_title
      from
        position_table
      where
        position_table.position_id = person_view.position_id and 
        rownum <= 3
      union all select '' from dual
      union all select '' from dual
      union all select '' from dual
     )
   where
     rownum <= 3
  )
from
  person_view
```

My actual error is that, it seems, the subquery that ensures at least 3 rows of input cannot reference the grandparents query to determine person_view.position_id.

I get ORA-00904: "PERSON_VIEW"."POSITION_ID": invalid identifier

Performance is not a huge concern, as this is a report that will not be run regularly, but I need to figure out a solution to aggregate this data with an absolute 3 columns of data.  Any guidance to help rewrite the query, or allow the subquery to access the relevant grandparent column is greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for very well written question. I wish they were all so clearly presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation in Oracle SQL: you can't reference a parent query element from a subquery more than 1 level deep.

I would use a function in such a case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_title(p_position_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   l_result       LONG;
   l_position_num NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT position_title
                FROM position_table
               WHERE position_table.position_id = p_position_id
                 AND rownum <= 3) LOOP
      l_result       := cc.position_title || ',';
      l_position_num := l_position_num + 1;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN l_result || rpad(',', 3 - l_position_num, ',');
END;
```

You query would look like this:

```
select
  name,
  phone,
  address,
  get_title(p.position_id) title
from person_view p
```

Comment: Is this a consistent limitation or a bug?  I've ran into similar problems before, but I think in theory you should be able
to reference from any level.  For example, this statement works with 6 levels (on 10.2.0.1.0): 
`select (select (select (select (select (select test.dummy from dual) from dual) from dual) from dual) from dual) from dual test;`

Comment: @jonearles: this is a known consistent limitation, see for example [this question on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932). Your case is really interesting, it seems that it is still considered one-level deep [the subqueries are all *scalar* subqueries]. This doesn't work for example: `SELECT (SELECT xx FROM (SELECT test.dummy xx FROM dual)) FROM dual test`